# Converting SQL Query to XML Query for SharePoint List

Tags: sql, xml

I'm using SQL Reporting 3.0 and I'm trying to query a SharePoint list. Since the SharePoint list can only be in XML inside of SQL reporting, I'm trying to figure out to to convert my SQL query into an XML query. The area I'm stuck at is inside of WHERE. I'm having difficulty with IN(@). Is there a way to convert this into an XML query? Thank you for your help its greatly appreciated.

SQL Query

```
    SELECT       Hours, Date, Project, ID, Created_By,Month
    FROM            TimeTracking
    WHERE        Project IN(@Project) AND Month IN(@Month)
```

XML Query

```
    <RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <ListName>Time Tracking</ListName>
      <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="Hours" />
        <FieldRef Name="Date" />
        <FieldRef Name="Project" />
        <FieldRef Name="ID" />
        <FieldRef Name="Created_By" />
        <FieldRef Name="Month" />
      </ViewFields>
      <Query>
        <Where>
                ?
        </Where>
      </Query>
    </RSSharePointList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on MSDN on using FOR XML PATH to return your query as XML. You can also add a root element by using ROOT.

Please refer to te following article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx